# ArcGIS Server REST Cache

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-9.3

The municipality that I work for is currently using the latest version of MSGovern CityView.  For those that have never used CityView, it's a software package that helps municipalities manage their assets and perform a variety of administrative tasks.  Within this software a GIS/spatial component is made available.  A user can perform non spatial queries on a variety of things (e.g. Parcels, Businesses, Parks, Utilities, etc.) and if they'd like, the information can be viewed on a map.

The current version of CityView uses ArcGIS Server to consume maps. The issue I’m having is an inconsistent rendering of maps once updates are made.  Within ArcGIS Server Manager the updates seem to take place, however, when I go over to REST (`http://hostname/ArcGIS/rest/services/mapservicename/MapServer`) to view the metadata as well as view the actual map, I notice that the updates have not been executed.

I've read through this [blog](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/10/08/clearing-the-arcgis-services-directory-cache-the-easy-way/), but I’m not sure if this is a task I should be caring out when I make updates to the map service.  I want to say this is what's causing the CityView problem, but I'm not sure. I’ve tried deleting the service, deleting browsing history and then republishing the service, but the result within REST is a previous version of the map service. I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.1 and ArcGIS Server 10.0.

Comment: Maybe its your browser cache? I had a similar problem and everytime i had to clear the Cache from my Chrome. e.g. create and publish service, and access with e.g. Chrome. Now update your service and try to access the same service with e.g. Firefox or IE

Comment: You may need to clear the REST cache to see the modifications - can you navigate to <servername>/arcgis/rest/admin?  If you have access to log in you will be able to see 'Clear Cache Options' where you can clear the rest cache.

Comment: Clearing REST cache worked when having the updates made available to CityView.  However, after clearing the Cache, REST still does take a bit of time show those updates.  Overall, the updates are now much more consistent. Maybe add that as an answer Tim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timothy never got around to making his comment from above as an answre, so I'm posting it here.

You may need to clear the REST cache to see the modifications - can you navigate to /arcgis/rest/admin? If you have access to log in you will be able to see 'Clear Cache Options' where you can clear the rest cache

Comment: Thank you for adding this as an answer - I didn't see that you had asked me to add it until now.